# TMUX key binding dependant on position in copy mode

Tags: tmux

I want `Pagedown` to exit `copy-mode` if it is pressed at the bottom of the scrolling page.

I have tried using `if-shell` with tests involving `#{scroll_region_lower}` and `#{scroll-region-upper}` but they don't seem to give the right results.

Is there a variable I can test that will tell me where in copy-mode scrolling I am?  The top of the page displays the position, I need a command to return the `0` from `[0/2270]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter copy mode with copy-mode -e (change your [ and/or PageUp bindings).